# How to blank the message box after sending sms and returning to the main activity

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
            sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + "12345"));
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hi 12345");
            sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
            startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 500);
```

I used this code to send sms to 12345. I returns automatically after sending sms to the main activity. but the message REMAINS there. I want to wipe it off after returning. help

Comment: R u using edit-text for entering character?

Comment: try my below code and let me know whether it is working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code.

Create **onResume** method and setText of your **Edit text** to blank. Eg...

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
     editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

Remember you have to use this method outside the onCreate Method.

Comment: I want a toast to show that message has been successfully submitted. But this on resume will be called even when the first time i enter in that activity

Comment: For that you can use static int variable and set it by default 0 and onclick of send button set it to 1 and then in onResume check whether the value of variable is 1 or not if yes then show toast message otherwise not.

Comment: Great! Thanks buddy, you must be laughing at me.

Comment: Not at all, if this answer helped you then please accept the answer by clicking right below my answer, since you are very new to stack overflow check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

After **startActivityForResult** on success Perform a function

```
public void clear() {
if(Success)
 edittext.setText("");    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an EditText, try this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + "12345"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hi 12345");
sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 500);
edittext.setText("");
```